# How to drop duplicates while streaming in spark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have a streaming job that streams data into delta lake in databricks spark, and I'm trying to drop duplicates while streaming so my delta data has no duplications. Here's what I have so far:

```
inputPath = "my_input_path"

schema = StructType("some_schema")

eventsDF = (
  spark
    .readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
    .csv(inputPath)
)

def upsertToDelta(eventsDF, batchId): 
  eventsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")

  eventsDF._jdf.sparkSession().sql("""
    MERGE INTO eventsDF t
    USING updates s
    ON s.deviceId = t.deviceId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
  """)


writePath = "my_write_path"
checkpointPath = writePath + "/_checkpoint"

deltaStreamingQuery = (eventsDF
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta)
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
  .outputMode("append")
  .queryName("test")
  .start(writePath)
)
```

I'm getting the error: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o398.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: eventsDF; line 2 pos 4`

But I just started to stream this data and haven't created any table yet.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking about the table not found or how to drop duplicates?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski How to drop duplicates

Comment: Why don't you use `Dataset.dropDuplicates` then?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I'm trying to drop duplicates while streaming data, my table is constantly having new data, can just perform dropDuplicates once.

Comment: You'll be dropping duplicates as they come until watermark. `Dataset` is a streaming query (not a structured one-off batch query). Have you tried it out?

Comment: Assuming you want to drop duplicates based on deviceId, have you tried adding ```.dropDuplicates("deviceId")``` while reading the stream?

Answer (score 0):

I find 2 issues with your code:

1. As you are calling Merge statement in function upsertToDelta. Spark is expecting a target table with which the "updates" tempView can be merged.

In the code:

MERGE INTO eventsDF t
USING updates s
ON s.deviceId = t.deviceId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *

eventsDF is suppose to be the target table name.

2. The above code itself will join the tempView with the target table and it will insert into the target table, when not matched.

Therefore, writePath in start() is not required.
.start(writePath)

Please note: You can also add update option to your merge code, if required.